# Test data should be separate from the rest of the automation code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-data

I am working in selenium with page object design pattern. I have got a feedback about my code and I want to make my code better.

**Code Review**

> "You need to keep the test data separately.  Not scattering all over
>   the script. Keep the test data in JSON.  And read it from there where
>   ever it is necessary."

**Test Data**

> Test data should be separate from the rest of the automation code. The
>   reason is this: if you do not separate your test data, as you add new
>   tests you will duplicate field identifiers and the data to enter. When
>   there is a change to the code, you will have a maintenance nightmare.

Also, if your test data is in a separate, non-compiled format, it's a lot easier for other people to add new tests. If the data format for each type of test is clearly defined, all that's needed to add an iteration of a test is to edit a text file and add a new row of data.

Anybody, please show an example? And above mentioned test data is using with the data provider, is it right?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @Rsf I need an example of  how to keep test data separatley?

Comment: You might do some research on "data driven" testing or "data driving" tests, also similar terms.

Comment: @AdrianHHH  Excuse me So i should learn data driven testing testing it is selenium framework right?  please tell me  the importance of learning JSON

Comment: @toastmaster I did not write "should", I wrote "might". Your review said it should use JSON. Data driven testing is applicable to many (perhaps all) testing systems and it can be done with JSON or with several other data formats (eg CSV, Spreadsheet, Database, plain text) depending on the needs and the working practices of the company.

Comment: @AdrianHHH  please give some examples then i can understand

Comment: @AdrianHHH  one of the most important framework in selenium is data driven testing right ?

Comment: @toastmaster There are some wonderful web search systems, such as Bing and Google. If you type into their search boxes terms such as "data driven testing" and "selenium data driving json" you will get many many examples.

Comment: @toastmaster - You need to learn more about programming, specifically data structures. JSON allows for very flexible data structures build "on-the-fly", dynamically. Using some dynamic language will help, Like Python or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "You need to keep the test data separately. Not scattering all over the script. Keep the test data in Json. And read it from there where ever it is necessary."

It depends.

**Are your test data bound to the test environment and system under test?** For instance, if you are reusing in your tests data that are defined in the system you test, then it's good to keep them in one place. This makes maintenance easier, e.g., when you want actual test user gets removed from the system, then you have only one place to update. It also makes easier to reuse same test data across different tests, e.g., same test user. 
However, if each of your tests is using different test data and those data are not bound to the system, it might be better to keep your test data closer to the test class. Otherwise, by updating test data for one test you may break another test.

> Also, if your test data is in a separate, non-compiled format, it's a lot easier for other people to add new tests. If the data format for each type of test is clearly defined, all that's needed to add an iteration of a test is to edit a text file and add a new row of data.

Again, it depends.

**Do you really have non-technical tests that will be adding new test data entries?** In a flight domain I worked we had less technical tests that were aware of booking flight format and it was easier for them to understand separate test data files than reading code would be. Where I work now we have more technical testers to work and writing test data in a separate Java class seems more natural to us.

**Are your test data easier to read in a from of separate files?** For instance, it was  useful for me to keep flight bookings as separate XML files when I was working in a flight domain. On the other hand, where I work now, it's more natural to describe test data in same programming language as the rest of the code.

**How complex is updating your test data?** If your test data are in the same programming language as your test scripts, then many things become easier:

- finding which tests are using given piece of test data with just one click in your IDE
- refactoring test data structure will be easier with just one click

Here's an example of same data that Lesmana Sitepu described, but this time as a Java class

```
public class TestUsers {

 public static final JOHN_SMITH = new User()
   .firstName("John")
   .lastName("Smith")
   .with(new Address()
    .streetAddress("21 2nd Street")
    .city("New York"));

}
```

Comment: hai please give some examples

Comment: @toastmaster added.

Comment: so this java class example is like a json format. and I don't know about json.  i want to study more about json

Comment: @toastmaster It's like a JSON but it is not JSON. And has certain advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the feedback you got, it seems that you keep your test data scattered all over your script. What your code reviewer means is that it will be much better if you separate your test data in JSON file, not directly put the value of your test data with your script/code. You could easily change the value of any given field/parameter you want to change for other tests.

This is an example of a Customer Form JSON file which you might see used to store configuration settings to setup your system. It might also be used to contain record information which can be easily shared across components using the simple JSON format.

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
     [
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": "212 555-1234"
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": "646 555-4567"
         }
     ]
 }
```

You could learn more about JSON [here](http://www.json.org/index.html) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

Also, [here](http://jsonlint.com/) is a useful website to validate your JSON file.

Hope this helps.